# How to dynamically add a new field to the database

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am developing a multi-tenant application, and I want each tenant to customize their record by adding a new field to the database.

My base user model contains => Username, Firstname, and Lastname. a tenant can decide to add more fields like Phonenumber, DateOfBirth, Country. e.t.c to their record.

I am currently using a relational database(PostgreSQL) and NodeJs

Comment: Try to include code samples and your real and exact data structure as it can be hard to understand the full context if there are any particular considerations that are implicitly understood for you, but not detailed in the question.

Comment: What you can do is define those fields in your model and make them not required and that gives users to add info into those fields if they want.

Comment: I currently don't have a working code for it yet, and I don't even know the fields the user might want to add to their record (They can decide to add any field to their table).

The approach that I am trying to take is that all tenant has it's own database so that it will be managed easily.

Just looking for a way to achieve this dynamically without having to run a migration to the database because it's almost impossible to control the migration